# mkdocs - dynamic list of child pages

Tags: mkdocs

Is there a way to dynamically generate a list of files under the current page's folder structure in mkdocs?  I'm looking for something kind of like the Confluence "children display" macro, so that if my folder structure is

```
Page1/index.md
Page1/subfolder/sub1.md
Page1/subfolder/sub2.md
Page2/index.md
```

then I want some way to list `subfolder` and its contents within the body of `Page1/index.md`.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of [mkdocs-macros](https://github.com/fralau/mkdocs_macros_plugin), which basically adds templating capabilities to your markdown pages. If you are willing to add [jinja2 code](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/) to your markdown pages, you could use that plugin. The object you are looking for is `{{ navigation }}`.

To see what is in there, just use, in any of your pages:

```markdown
# My page's title

{{ context(navigation) | pretty }}
```

This is not the full answer, but should get you started :-)